# Reverse a string in C solution segfaulting

Tags: c, string, segmentation-fault, reverse

I've come up with the following solution in C for reversing a string:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void reverse(char * head);

void main() {

  char * s = "sample text";
  reverse(s);
  printf("%s", s);
}

void reverse(char * head) {

  char * end = head;
  char tmp;

  if (!head || !(*head)) return;

  while(*end) ++end;

  --end;

  while (head < end) {
    tmp = *head;
    *head++ = *end;
    *end-- = tmp;
  }
}
```

However my solution is segfaulting. According to GDB, the offending line is the following:

```
*head++ = *end;
```

The line segfaults on the first iteration of the while loop. end points to the last character of the string "t" and head points to the beginning of the string. So why isn't this working?

Comment: The \0 is automatic in string literals

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Change

```
char * s = "sample text";
```

To

```
char s[] = "sample text";
```

"sample text" is a string literal which may reside in a read-only section of your address space. Using the array syntax ensures this string is copied to stack, which is writable.

Comment: Upvoting yours rather than codaddict's identical answer because you put an explanation in.

Comment: Maybe slightly off-topic, but what's the benefit of having "sample text" in read-only memory? To save space?

Comment: @Jeff, if you have a hundred places in your code that all use the same string literal, the compiler will only put one copy into your executable. Now imagine if one of them modified that constant. That's why it's in read-only memory (that and it's, well, a *constant*).

Answer (score 11):

Your `s` is pointing to a string literal:

```
char * s = "sample text";
```

In the function `reverse` you are trying to modify the string literal which results in undefined behavior.

To fix this make `s` a char array:

```
char s[] = "sample text";
```